# 60 dB gain at 20 MHz

Tags: amplifier, rf

I am designing an IF amplifier circuit that needs roughly 60 dB of gain at 20 MHz. I was considering a cascade of 3 x 20 dB MMIC gain blocks but I am wondering if there is a better way?

The disadvantage of the MMIC approach is that the power consumption is roughly 35 mA per device. So just wondering if I have overlooked something better. Cheers!

Comment: How about three tuned MOSFET stages? Easy gain control is an added bonus.

Comment: MMICs are overkill, they're burning all that power in order to get tons of bandwidth.  If you only need 20MHz Leon's suggestion is a good way to go.  You could use bipolars too if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Leon & John. I think I will stick to the MMIC route for the prototype then design in a discrete replacement

Answer (score 2):

If your need is relatively narrowband then tuned circuits could be employed. 20 MHz is rather close to 21.4 MHZ which is a standard IF frequency .So you could use some 21.4 MHz standard IFTs and not have to wind coils . They will tune to 20MHz with little or no extra capacitance .You could use some cascode stages which remove miller effect and are well documented in textbooks and will be easy to set up .What I have done is cascoded a MPF102 JFET with a cheap standard BC547 npn BJT  and used a 12VDC supply         .It can be shown that the BJT on top will outperform a JFET pair or a dualgate mosfet because the BJT has much more transconductance than any fet meaning that miller is much less.Because the BJT on top effectively runs common base it doesn't need a high Ft so high voltage operation is a possibility.I experimented with a MJE 340 npn BJT on top with 15 VDC on the base .I used 100 VDC for HT.I also tried a MPSA42 npn BJT with the same result                 .This was to replace an IF   EF89  pentode valve .      Also the high input and output impedances mean that you don't need to tap your coils which simplifies things.I set up my jfets with an unbypassed         330 ohm source resister giving 3mA measured .Beware of unit to unit spreads .Your current may be different but you wont blow the FET with a 330ohm start.I guess that 2 stages will be needed.